# Option -s is deprecated, use -video_size. Option video_size not found

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I'm trying to play a video like a preview before rendering:

```
ffplay test.mp4 -af "volume=8.0,atempo=4.0" -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2,setpts=1/4*PTS" -s 640x480 -aspect 4:2
```

Without `-s` its working fine, but when I add `-s` its outputs error:

```
Option -s is deprecated, use -video_size.
Option video_size not found.
```

Let me know the syntax. And some times after converting I don't find the change in the details
[image]

```
ffmpeg -i 21.mp4 -vf "scale=1280*720" 21_edit.mkv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## These errors are specific to `ffplay`

- `-s` is deprecated for `-video_size` only in `ffplay`, not `ffmpeg`.
- `-video_size` is used to manually tell `ffplay` the size for videos that do not contain a header (such as raw video). **It is not used to resize videos.**

## To resize/scale video

Use the [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filter:

```
ffplay -af "volume=8.0,atempo=4.0" -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2,setpts=1/4*PTS,scale=640:-1" test.mp4
```

## To resize the player window

Use the `-x` or `-y` options:

- `-x` *width*
  Force displayed width.
- `-y` *height*
  Force displayed height.

Example:

```
ffplay -af "volume=8.0,atempo=4.0" -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2,setpts=1/4*PTS" -x 640 test.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

-s option is depricated in ffmpeg. So you can use scale filter directly to specify the video dimension. The modified ffplay command is

```
ffplay test.mp4 -af "volume=8.0,atempo=4.0" -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2,setpts=1/4*PTS,scale=640*480" -aspect 4:2
```

Comment: one more thing how can I confirm that it converted sometimes in properties i don't find it
than you

Comment: you can use ffprobe command to find the video properties. sample command be like ffprobe -print_format json <file-name>. it will display the properties in json format.